# google maps only loads grey box and works in drag event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, world-map

I am trying to add google world map in my template.But initially it loads in grey color,while dragging on the grey color it loads the world map chart.

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.8505, 76.2711),
        zoom: 8,
        minZoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(chartId), mapOptions);
```

This is the code i have used to draw chart.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6nJJ.png) will be the grey color chart which comes on loading.
While dragging chart will load like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzCZy.png). Can anyone suggest a method to solve this issue.I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If the maps is visible at startup but you have only a grey box, be sure that map div id is properly styled with width and height:

```
<div id="chartId" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

If work with this assigment but you want a height 100% then you must assign to all the parent div height 100%; or a fixed height.

Comment: I have specified width and height to 100% for that div as well as it's parent div's. Again it shows same like that only.

Comment: just for text try using 400px; for width and height (not %)

Comment: worldmap is not working when width or height is more than 700px.

Comment: try and let me know if goggle maps work with 400px;  if yes  then the problem is in the heigth of all container parent of the maps and you must assign to all of this  hieght 100%; if not.. the problem is another ..

Comment: answer  updated .. google maps require a true dimensioned  height so you must have or  a fidex height or you must have an assigned  height for all parent div body included

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the map container has proper height and width initially. If not, try specifying the height and width explicitly.

Comment: I have specified width and height to 100% for that div as well as it's parent div's. Again it shows same like that only.

Comment: worldmap is not working when width or height is more than 700px.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it?